# Perform action every 10

Tags: php, loops

I have a simple php for loop which looks like this:

```
<?php
for($x=0; $x<100; $x++){
    echo $x . ' ';
}
?>
```

I would like to use the `sleep();` function every other 10. So for example the loop should sleep at 10 then again at 20 then again at 30 etc.

I could make a switch and just do every possible option and do it that way, or with if statements. But this is just not the most optimal way. Is there a better way do to this?

Comment: `if( $x % 10 == 0 ) sleep();`?

Comment: @Kevin use RamRaider's answer as an if else block in your code

Comment: @RamRaider I think you should add an answer

Comment: Flagged as duplicate as linked by @executable. You really should've google'd. Also, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep for 5 seconds, based on RamRaider code:

```
<?php
for($x=0; $x<100; $x++){
    echo $x . ' ';
    if( $x % 10 == 0 )
    {
        sleep(5);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as below:

```
for($x=0; $x<100; $x++)
{
    echo $x . ' ';
    if($x % 10 == 0) sleep(5); //this sleeps for 5 seconds
}
```